# .NET Real Time Data Chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, winforms, infragistics

I want to make a real time data chart that shows last 10 minutes in asp.net or winForms.

[This is the image that i want to make it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezN1N.png)

I added the series but could not add datapoints. I searched a lot but i failed.

I use infragistics by the way.

Below code generates random numbers and shows that number in the charts. It works but just last number that [i can see it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDN97.png) not last 10 minutes.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = (1 * 1000); // 1 secs
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int rnd=r.Next(1, 150);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
        dt.Rows.Add(rnd, DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), "HH:mm:ss", null));

        NumericTimeSeries series = new NumericTimeSeries();      
        series.DataBind(dt, "Date", "Value");
        NumericTimeDataPoint ndp1 = new NumericTimeDataPoint(DateTime.Now, rnd, "ilk", false);
        NumericTimeDataPoint ndp2 = new NumericTimeDataPoint(DateTime.Now, 5.0, "iki", false);
        series.Points.Add(ndp1);
        series.Points.Add(ndp2);
        ultraChart2.Data.SwapRowsAndColumns = true;
        ultraChart2.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly,

On each tick, you are **replacing** your data instead of adding to it.

Try initializing the series once in the *Form1_Load* handler, and on each tick, just add new values to it, without creating a new DataTable, rebinding it to the series and so on.

---

To make things clear,

Your *timer_Tick* handler should have only 4 lines of code:

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NumericTimeDataPoint ndp1 = new NumericTimeDataPoint(DateTime.Now, rnd, "ilk", false);
    NumericTimeDataPoint ndp2 = new NumericTimeDataPoint(DateTime.Now, 5.0, "iki", false);
    _series.Points.Add(ndp1);
    _series.Points.Add(ndp2);
}
```

Declare the _series as a private member, initialize it from the *Form1_Load* handler, and you should be good to go.

Comment: I did some changes but it throws errors. Would you edit the pastebin, that would be awesome for me. http://pastebin.com/vqDsNUv1

Comment: I will guess, and say that the problem is that you are declaring _NumericTimeSeries _series = new NumericTimeSeries();_ inside the Load handler. Put it outside, as a private member.